Difference between integer division vs floating point division + int conversion
Assuming x ≥ 0 and y > 0 are both 64-bit unsigned integers would there be any correctness difference between below implementation and x // y?
def int_divide(x, y):
    return int(x / float(y))


Yes, for example:
>>> int_divide(10**18, 3)
333333333333333312
>>> 10**18 // 3
333333333333333333

The latter is correct, the former is not.

@MarkRansom I can add something, but I firmly believe that it speaks for itself. Doesn't it?

@MarkRansom How about now? That should really suffice to show that there is a difference, and if someone thinks the first result is the correct one, there's something wrong with them :-)

@MarkRansom The question is "would there be any correctness difference". This answer clearly answers that. (And if you agree that those comments are answering, then flag them to help get them deleted faster.)

(No, the answer is not different.)[imgur.com/a/bZf4hKo]

Your latest edit actually weakens your case.

@MarkRansom How so?

@SuramuthuR You used other values and not even the expressions they're asking about.

Your original choice of numbers showed a greater difference, and dividing by 1 is hardly realistic.

@MarkRansom Neither of those matter. Wrong is wrong. But ok, I'll revert.

This is logically not correct. When the number of digits go beyond 18, this will try to simplify in terms of x10**18. So the last digit is negligible. It doesn't mean that both values are different. Screenshot

I've edited my answer for more clarity. Please read

@SuramuthuR Again you used other values and not even the expressions they're asking about. And your results may be equal, but that's irrelevant. Mine aren't, and one example of inequality suffices.
